# Chrome 16 websocket binary

Tags: html, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to set up a websocket server in node.js but having problems. I found a bit code here on stackoverflow and heres the servercode I have now:

```
var net = require("net"), crypto = require("crypto"), users = [];

net.createServer(function(socket) {
    this.name = "Anonymous";
    users.push(socket);     

    socket.on('data', function(buffer) {
        if(buffer.toString('utf-8').substring(0, 14) === "GET / HTTP/1.1") {
            this.securyPattern = /Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)/g;
            this.key = this.securyPattern.exec(buffer);
            this.magic = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
            this.sha1 = crypto.createHash("sha1");
            this.sha1.update(this.key[1] + this.magic);
            this.accept = this.sha1.digest("base64");
            socket.write("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nUpgrade: WebSocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: " + this.accept + "\r\n\r\n");
        } else {
            console.log(buffer);
            console.log(buffer.toString('utf-8'));
        }
    });

    socket.on('end', function() {
        users.splice(users.indexOf(socket), 1);
    });
}).listen(1337);
```

Everything works fine as it connects, and users.length is updated when that happens and when someone disconnects.

The problem is that I dont know how to read messages except the header (which is plain text), so the lines that I have to print the buffer and buffer.toString('utf-8') only prints something binary different all the time, example for the word "hello":

```
<Buffer 81 85 71 dc c1 02 19 b9 ad 6e 1e>
??q??☻↓??n▲
<Buffer 81 85 8e 8f 0f a2 e6 ea 63 ce e1>
????☼???c??
```

I'm sending this "hello" with Chrome 16 using:
myWebSocket.send("hello"); where myWebSocket is the WebSocket object.

So how do I read and write messages to the socket with this?

Comment: Don't try to do it yourself. Use socket.io, it has a nice API around realtime messaging between server and browser and a lot of fallbacks (flashsockets, long polling, ...) in case the browser is too dumb.

Comment: I have been looking on how to use that but I couldnt find a download link and I think I found that its not for Windows, do you know if it is?

Comment: It should work on windows. You should install it with npm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that after the handshake, the data is framed with 2 or more header bytes at the beginning of each frame. Also, note that payload sent from the client (browser) to the server is masked using a simple 4-byte running XOR mask.

The framing definition is [defined in section 5 of the spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17#section-5)

Instead of implementing your own WebSocket server in Node you might consider using a higher level abstraction like [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my code on handling that buffer:

```js
socket.ondata = function(src,start,end) {
    src = src.slice(start,end);
    var maskKeys = [src[2],src[3],src[4],src[5]];
    var dest = new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<src.length-6;i++){
        var mKey = maskKeys[i%4];
        dest[i] = mKey ^ src[6+i];
    }
    console.log(new Buffer(dest).toString());
}
```

Found from here: http://songpengfei.iteye.com/blog/1178310